# Keeping angular attributes out of my HTML

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm using AngularJS in my web app, which isn't a single page app but a more traditional many html pages app.

When I add angular-powers to my asp.net mvc Razor view cshtml files (effectively html files), I don't like that I'm adding more view markup that is then outputted in the HTML. For example, a dropdown list looks like:

```
<select ng-model="pagerInfo.filterText" ng-options="g.ID as g.GroupName + ' (' + g.InboxCount + ')' for g in groups"
```

I don't want all that angular noise to be visible in the markup. So what do I do?

I've tried refactoring it with `directives` instead - so the above snippet could be replaced with

```
<select group-filter/>
```

.. but that seems to present problems, for example the model binding with `ng-model=` doesn't seem to work when defined in the directive template. Is that the recommended way, or should I be doing something else to handle this?

Thanks

Comment: What is wrong with the *noise* exactly?

Comment: It feels like I'm leaking view logic to the HTML. The HTML should just be a view, and it feels as though controller logic is leaking into it. Maybe this is accepted, and it's just my server/client background that makes me feel odd about this. Is it just me?

Comment: I'm not quite sure why you would use AngularJS if you are not doing a SPA (Single Page Application)... AngularJS is a MVW (Model-View-Whatever). It should be used as a SPA.

Comment: @snaplemouton AngularJS is not exclusively for SPA apps. It's for building client-rich web apps, be that SPA or not. I'm finding it invaluable for creating rich UIs that are clean, testable, and not full of brittle jquery dom manipulation

Comment: @Matt Roberts Yes I understand it can be used with a non SPA, but well... It just feel weird to use the MVC pattern in web on a non SPA.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a simple template directive using replace and transclude like so:

```
<template-directive></template-directive>

    app.directive('templateDirective', [function () {
    return {
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<select ng-model="selectedItems" multiple ng-options="g.Id as g.Label for g in items" ></select>'
    }
}]);
```